# is there a way to boot code written in a managed language?

Tags: c#, boot

The question says it all. Can I compile C# to native code and boot it? I know of Cosmos and Singularity, but I was wondering if there are more recent techniques or tools. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can compile to native code using Mono:

http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Runtime#Ahead-of-time_compilation

Still, you won't be able to write an OS with that. Its impossible to write an entire OS in C#, Cosmos and Singularity will have portions that aren't managed code.

Or of course, you can set your code to boot at Windows Startup - .NET applications will run just fine once Windows has booted up to the login screen and beyond.

Comment: As far as I can see, Cosmos doesn't have anything written in a language other than C#, at least from what they say on their website. Singularity does, though.

Comment: The compiler won't be in C#, unless it was first compiled to native code ->"Cosmos includes a compiler (IL2CPU, which is part of Cosmos) that reads the input file (usually the shell) and Cosmos libraries and compiles the resulting IL to x86 code."

Comment: Right. That's what I knew about. I was wondering if there are newer tools.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by "boot it"... If you mean "boot on a machine as an OS" you would need to set up a bootloader and re-write most of the c# functions yourself. You would also have to set up all the machine-specific features from a lower-level language (assembly/c[++]/etc). Basically, there's no way to have it boot by itself without a significant amount of work.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to author a windows service that is set to start with the system. I believe there are other ways to accomplish this but this maybe 'the easiest'.

Comment: The OP means "boot" as in "boot from a floppy drive" LOL. "Singularity", which he mentioned, is an OS.

Comment: Perhaps I should have used the term "system" service rather than windows service, I am just more accustomed to differentiating from web services. OP was wanting something "other" than Singularity, an OS which supports the .NET CLR. But you can't boot to Windows from a bootable DVD/CD and start a service... oh, wait, you can....